# Simple blog in Ruby on Rails but having restricted privileges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just created a simple blog (by lynda tutorials), but it is for an admin user who has all access rights such as add, delete and update posts, users and comments. But I needed only one adminuser and all rights to him. All other users only add comments and create, update and delete posts. How can I do this?

Or how can I add only one admin user such that when he enters that specific username and password he gets all access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a chapter in Railscasts about cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan). This makes something similar to what you want.